Get the Acronym of a Phrase in PHP
How do I get the acronym for a phrase in Laravel or php while also considering hyphen separated words, for instance:
Technical Learning Curve in Front-end should give me TLCIFE
So far this is what I came up with:
function getAbbr($phrase) {
    $words = explode(' ', $phrase);
    $abbreviation = '';
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        $abbreviation .= strtoupper(substr($word, 0, 1));
    }

    return $abbreviation;
}

echo getAbbr("Technical Learning Curve in Front-end");


For now, it works but does not account for hyphens I could work that in but it will just increase the number of code lines which I'm also avoiding, also, I was wondering if Laravel or PHP have any native functions or helpers that could handle it more optimally.

"Laravel or PHP have any native functions" - Not to my knowledge, and there's caveats to what you're trying to do. Typically, abbreviations (actually, this would be an acronym, abbreviations are shortened, like abbr. is an abbreviation for abbreviation) ignore short works like "in", or "the", so your's would generally be TLCFE instead of TLCIFE. Your's could be optimized or shortened using array_map(), and implode(), or your could leverage Laravel's Collection class, but you've got a decent first approach there

Your code produces TCLIF, not TCLIFE as you have stated is desired. Instead of explode on space, I'd preg_split on non-word characters.

Code golfed: function abbr($s){return strtoupper(join('',array_map(fn($w)=>$w[0],preg_split('/\W/',$s))));}
